# Want to run below tcpreplay using python code on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, wireshark, tcpreplay

Want to run below tcpreplay command using python code on Linux instance can you please give a working sample
tcpreplay-edit -i ens7 -I ens8 --loop=20000 --enet-smac srcmac,dstmac --enet-dmac dstmac,srcmac -c /home/cache.cache /home/pcap.pcap &

experts can you please guide me